# Why method addMouseListener doesn't need a super?

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, super

My question is when I create a class inherited from JPanel, why don't use super.addMouseListener() to add a listener? I thought this method is in the super class which is the JPanel.
here's the code:

```
private class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{
    private int prefwid, prefht;

    // Initialize the DrawPanel by creating a new ArrayList for the images
    // and creating a MouseListener to respond to clicks in the panel.
    public DrawPanel(int wid, int ht)
    {
        prefwid = wid;
        prefht = ht;

        chunks = new ArrayList<Mosaic>();

        // Add MouseListener to this JPanel to respond to the user
        // pressing the mouse.  In your assignment you will also need a
        // MouseMotionListener to respond to the user dragging the mouse.
        addMouseListener(new MListen());
    }
```

Comment: because it is inherited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's not necessary.

You don't declare a method `addMouseListener` in the `DrawPanel` class, so the compiler checks superclasses for such a method, and finds it in `java.awt.Component`. Because this method is inherited by the `DrawPanel` class, it's fine to invoke it here.

If you want to know the in-depth reason why, you'd need to read [JLS Sec 15.12, "Method Invocation Expressions"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). It's not exactly light reading, however.

I think that the key sentences are:

> **[Sec 15.12.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1)**
>
> For the class or interface to search, there are six cases to consider, depending on the form that precedes the left parenthesis of the MethodInvocation:
>
> - If the form is MethodName, that is, just an Identifier, then:
>
>   - If the Identifier appears in the scope of a visible method declaration with that name (§6.3, §6.4.1), then:
>   - If there is an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a member, let T be the innermost such type declaration. The class or interface to search is T.
>   - ...

So `T` is `DrawPanel`.

> **[Sec 15.12.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.1)**
>
> The class or interface determined by compile-time step 1 (§15.12.1) is searched for all member methods that are potentially applicable to this method invocation; members inherited from superclasses and superinterfaces are included in this search.

So a method called `addMouseListener` is searched for in `DrawPanel` and all of its superclasses.

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you!